# Python В массив внутри if добавляется только последнее значение

Tags: python, массивы, if

Мне необходимо, чтобы по нажатию на кнопки и получению соответствующего callback - tvorog, moloko И так далее элемент добавлялся в массив.
Но вместо этого, в массиве остается только последний call.data сколько бы до этого не вызывались другие.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
        global ingredients
        ingredients = []

        if call.data == "tvorog":
            ingredients.append('tvorog')

        if call.data == "moloko":
            ingredients.append('moloko')

        if call.data == "muka":
            ingredients.append('muka')
            
        if call.data == "eggs":
            ingredients.append('eggs')


@bot.message_handler(regexp="Готово")
def gotovo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ingredients)
```

В итоге при каждом выводе ingredients (в message_handler) выдает последнюю вызванную if c одним элементом.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что за `add`? `ingredients` это список?

Comment: Логично... но если я выношу ingredients за пределы функции, то к ней нет доступа для записи...

Comment: add, это я эксперементировал, думал со списком прокатит.

Comment: Так зачем вы зануляете список в начале функции? Попробуйте убрать `ingredients = []`

Comment: вы вызываете функцию которая делает ingredients = [] при каждом вызове. там всегда будет максимум 1 элемент

Comment: вне функции напишите это. перенесите до функции эту строку. global ingredients темболее у вас есть

Comment: @dIm0n тогда как программа поймет что это массив? и куда будут записываться значения?

Comment: @DmitryArtamonov Интик уже ответил выше

Comment: @DmitryArtamonov прочтите пожалуйста https://python-scripts.com/scope там не много текста, но это важный момент в питоне

Comment: @DmitryArtamonov `global` не создаёт переменную, она просто говорит интерпретатору, в какой области видимости искать переменную - в глобальной

Answer (score 3):

При каждом вызове функции у вас обновляется переменная ingredients. Вынесите её вне функции.

```
ingredients = []
def callback_inline(call):
```

Comment: В таком случае - в массив добавляется первый вызванный callback. Реакции на другие callback-и - нет.

Comment: @DmitryArtamonov, как я понимаю, при выборе одного из 4 значений, у вас не зацикливается функция ingredients. У вас она сейчас работает так, вызывается функция, выбирается кнопкой 1 из 4 значений, в функции находится нужный if, добавляет элемент в массив и выходит из функции.

Comment: @DmitryArtamonov, в таком случае, кэшируйте значения, либо зациклите функцию, чтобы при выборе и записи одного нужного значения, вы не выходили из функции и не пересоздавали массив.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @DmitryArtamonov, с помощью while. Вставьте перед if, while. Что по поводу кэширования, Погуглите. Введите в поиске декораторы logger, cached. К сожалению подсказать не могу так как не вижу как работает бот и в целом весь код.